# I am trying to build a Discord Music Bot. When I send a command, the bot sees "!play" but not the message after it

Tags: javascript, discord.js, youtube-data-api

I am working on building a Discord Music Bot. Right now, when I send the command in Discord "!play " I get no response from the bot. It seems the bot returns the message content as empty. Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const youtubeSearch = require("youtube-search");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const { YT_API_KEY, DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN } = process.env;

if (!YT_API_KEY) {
  console.error("Missing YouTube API key!");
  process.exit(1);
}

if (!DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN) {
  console.error("Missing Discord bot token!");
  process.exit(1);
}

const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });

const opts = {
  maxResults: 1,
  key: YT_API_KEY,
  type: "video",
  videoCategoryId: "10",
};

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", async (msg) => {
  console.log("Received play command!: " + msg.content);
  if (!msg.content.trim()) {
    return; // Ignore empty or whitespace-only messages
  }

  console.log(`Received message: ${msg.content}`);
  console.log(`Message length: ${msg.content.length}`);

  if (msg.content.startsWith("!play")) {
    console.log("Received play command!");

    const channel = msg.member?.voice.channel;
    console.log(`Channel: ${channel}`);

    if (!channel) {
      console.log("User not in a voice channel!");
      return msg.reply(
        "You need to join a voice channel before I can play music!"
      );
    }

    const query = msg.content.substring(6).trim();
    try {
      const results = await youtubeSearch(query, opts);
      console.log("Results:", results);

      if (results.length === 0) {
        return msg.reply("No video results found!");
      }

      const connection = await channel.join();
      connection.on("error", console.error);
      const stream = ytdl(results[0].link, { filter: "audioonly" });
      console.log(`Playing: ${results[0].title}`);
      console.log(`URL: ${results[0].link}`);
      const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

      dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
        channel.leave();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      msg.reply("An error occurred while playing the song!");
    }
  }
});

client.login(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

I have tried using:

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  console.log("Received play command!: " + msg.content);
  if (!msg.content.trim()) {
    return; // Ignore empty or whitespace-only messages
  }
```

And also get no response from msg.content

Does anyone see what might be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: didn't Discord ban bots from seeing message text? don't you have to use slash commands now?